# Can interface implementations be restricted to an assembly?

Tags: c#

I can restrict C# class inheritance to the assembly through internal or private protected constructors. But is something similar possible with interfaces?

Why I want this?

I try to create a framework where specific interfaces exist. For simplicity I call them `IInput`, `IOutput` and `IInAndOut`. The latter inherits the other two.

Those can be used in several places in the framework and there are many implementations provided by the framework as well. Now I want to prevent the user from providing his own implementation. He should only be able to use existing implementations or derive from more specialized classes which already implement the interface.

I could do this with abstract classes instead which have private protected ctors but this won't allow to inherit two other abstract classes.

So I need something like a sealed or use-only interface which can only be implemented in my own assembly.

Is there something like this in C#?

Comment: Why not make the interface Internal? If any of your properties or methods need public access modifiers, then you would have to use explicit implementation, but it should work. One might ask why it matters if someone _tries_ to implement the interface? The work around to use an interface and to try and obfuscate it from external assemblies is usually a lot more effort than it is worth.

Comment: The interface is often passed to public functions of the framework so the interface needs to be public.

Comment: The things you can do with the framework are fixed. The interface is more of "what implementations you can use from the framework in that situation". It has to be ensured that implementations do specific things and I can't force it on external implementations.

Comment: Maybe I have to use generics and constraint to a abstract base class and some interfaces. This way I can enforce multiple interfaces and my own logic through the class.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of effort for negligible business value. Please provide a code example or more information on the business constraint, although achievable, what are the benefits to this other than to stifle the creativity of the consumers of your assembly? It frustrates me to no end when I come across framework internal interface or classes that I need to implement, but I can still use reflection or IL injection to get the job done when I need to.

Answer (score 0):

For the users of the framework I would suggest to offer **classes** where the specific IO methods are implemented. To prevent the users from overriding these methods, they can be marked as `sealed`, but the classes may be used as base classes for new derived classes.

For the developers of the framework you can use interfaces. In this case I would suggest to declare the interfaces as `internal` since you don't want the framework's users to implement the interfaces and, consequently, they don't need to see the interfaces. Currently (since C# 8.0), interfaces can contain implementations of some or all methods if this is convenient in the project.

Another option for the framework developers is to offer abstract classes, where the specific IO methods are marked as `abstract`. Also in this case a class can contain an implementation of a method, which would not be marked as `abstract`, but rather as `virtual`. Abstract classes have an advantage over interfaces that they enforce a more rigid structure of project components.

Comment: Thanks. But here comes the problem with multiple inheritance. The IInAndOut has IInput and IOutput as a base interface. This won't work with classes unfortunately.

Comment: Another problem is that the interface/class should be able to pass to public methods as a parameter so the interface/class has to be public.

Comment: You could simply throw, if implementations that don't belong to your framework, are passed in.
And tell your clients that custom implementations are not accepted.

Comment: @Robert If you offer classes you can hide the multiple inheritance issue by having the classes to implement one or more interfaces as required.
The classes would be public, including the specific methods. But the methods would be `sealed`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can make a **public** interface which can only be implemented internally but it requires a little work around as there is no keyword for this.

```
//Your framework class implementing interface that is publicly accessible but cannot be implemented outside of your framework assembly.
public class FrameworkClass : IFrameworkOnlyInterface
{
   NotImplementable IFrameworkOnlyInterface.CannotBeImplemented()
   {
      return null;
   }
}

//Your interface that will be visible and accessible for user of your framework but cannot be implemented in outside assemblies.
public interface IFrameworkOnlyInterface
{
   //A throw-away internal method returning internal type to dissalow implementation from outside of this assembly.
   internal NotImplementable CannotBeImplemented();
}

//Internal class used as a throw-away type to dissalow implementation of public interface outside of your assembly.
internal class NotImplementable
{

}
```

Users of your framework will be able to derive from your FrameworkClass and use it as normal, they will also be able to cast it to IFrameworkOnlyInterface and use its methods apart from CannotBeImplemented() method or any other method you mark as internal.
If you do not want users to access IFrameworkOnlyInterface at all then all you have to do is mark the IFrameworkOnlyInterface as internal.

Comment: Interesting approach. But it looks a bit hacky. And as I need the interface to be public (this is what is passed to framework functions), the `CannotBeImplemented` method would be visible. I guess such functionality should be provided by the language somehow but it is most likely an edge case. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The CannotBeImplemented method should not be visible to any outside assembly as its marked as internal, if it somehow still is visible you can try try marking the method with `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` attribute. Remember it will still be visible for you in your project. I have tested it in Visual Studio 2022 and it was invissible in another project without the need of the EditorBrowsable attribute.